# Fetch xml with HttpWebRequest in Windows phone

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest

I'm using httpwebrequest to fetch some xml document, the code is as followed. When I call

```
HttpGetMethod http = new HttpGetMethod();
http.Request("http://sample.com/xml.php");
```

It works fine, then I use the

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(xml);

                XElement element = document.Element("statuses");
                IEnumerable<XElement> statusesElements = element.Elements("status");

                foreach (var elx in statusesElements)
                {}
```

to parse the xml document. But sometimes there cause a exception, then I traced to find that the returned xml string contains the "e48"(I'm using the Fiddler to find the returned xml string), as shown in the pic. But I can't figure out the reason, it's so strange, what's the "e48"? Could anybody help?

Thanks.

[image]

```
public class HttpGetMethod
    {
        public WebCallBack CallBack;

        public void Request(string url)
        {
            var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
            IAsyncResult result = null;

            result = (IAsyncResult)request.BeginGetResponse(ResponseCallback, request);
        }

        private void ResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            try
            {
                var request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
                var response = request.EndGetResponse(result);

                using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {

                        if (CallBack != null)
                        {
                            var str = reader.ReadToEnd();
                            CallBack(str);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate
                {
                    CallBack(ex.ToString());
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

The debug output is:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
System.Xml.XmlException: '', hexadecimal value 0x0C, is an invalid character. Line 897, position 14.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Int32 res, String resString, String[] args)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Int32 pos, Int32 res, String resString, String[] args)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowInvalidChar(Char[] data, Int32 length, Int32 invCharPos)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseCDataOrComment(XmlNodeType type, Int32& outStartPos, Int32& outEndPos)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseCDataOrComment(XmlNodeType type)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseCData()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Parse
```

Here is the Raw response ih Fiddle:

[image]

Comment: The thing that's even more strange is that the exception trace you print shows that the invalid character is on line 897, at position 14.    I would have expected an exception to occur with a message stating that the invalid character were at the very beginning of the data if the e48 character were the problem.

Comment: If it shows in the raw response in Fiddler there is a bug in the server code that generates the file.  You need to debug it.

Comment: Yeah looks like a server problem, if you can't access the server then just maybe try to conditionally remove it e.g. if( xml.StartsWith("e48")){ xml = xml.Substring(3) }

Comment: The response from the server is chunked (see the Transfer-Encoding header for confirmation).  The e48 line gives the number of bytes in the first chunk.  Does the response end \r\n0\r\n?  If it does, your server probably is behaving correctly.

Comment: Thinking about this a little more, it'd be worth trying copying the response stream to a memory stream, taking the bytes from that stream, converting to utf8 (or whatever other encoding the response gives) then feeding that into your xml parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO in this specific scenario use regex such as "^[^<]*" in

```
String result = Regex.Replace(htmlDocument, @"^[^<]*", System.String.Empty, RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

to remove the preceeding garbage chars

Comment: public static string CleanInvalidXmlChars(string text)
        {
         return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(text, @"[^<]*", string.Empty);
        }       But it still cause an exception. :-(

Comment: These aren't garbage characters - they give the length of the first chunk of response.

Comment: @simonc Thanks, simonc. You're right, and I've found a way to deal with the chunk response, thanks a lot.

Comment: @ellic And what is your solution? Could you please post that here.